# c# await class.methodAsync1().methodAsync2()

Tags: c#, async-await

Возможно ли использовать асинхронные методы в цепочке?

```
var blog = new Blog();
await blog.ValidateAsync().InsertAsync().SaveAsync();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет. Все асинхронные методы возвращают `Task`, а чтобы добраться до результата таска, нужно дописать ключевое слово `await`. Поскольку второй метод вам нужно вызвать у результата первого таска, то нужно сперва дождаться этого таска. И так далее. Получится следующая вложенная цепочка:

```
await (await (await blog.ValidateAsync()).InsertAsync()).SaveAsync();
```

Можно оформить это костылями с использованием методов расширения, где `InsertAsync()` будет являться методом расширения для некоего `Task<T>`, где `T` содержит все необходимое для работы метода. Аналогично и с `SaveAsync()`. И остальные ожидания будут происходить уже внутри этих методов.

Однако в вашем случае не советовал бы так делать. Fluent-синтаксис хорошо в весьма определенных сценариях, а цепочка "валидация - вставка - сохранение", на мой взгляд, в них не входит. Лучше всего вызывать эти методы последовательно, не экономить на строчках и не стремиться к "красоте".

Answer (score 3):

В такой цепочке - **нет, нельзя**.

Можно написать разве что вот так:

```
await (await (await blog.ValidateAsync()).InsertAsync()).SaveAsync();
```

Но лучше все-таки явно разделять разные операции:

```
await blog.ValidateAsync();
await blog.InsertAsync();
await blog.SaveAsync();
```

Comment: Во втором варианте нужны присваивания, вероятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy не думаю. Очень уж вариант автора похож на Fluent-синтаксис, а там в таких случаях this возвращается

Comment: Ну возможно и так.